# Topic Modelling using RPy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2, lda, topic-modeling

I wish to use LDA in Python using RPy. I have already tried this using `gensim` package but I still wish to try `RPy2` out.

While using R I use this code:

```
library(RTextTools)
library(topicmodels)
library(tm)

...Get Data Here and Store to `data`...

matrix <- create_matrix(as.vector(data$body), 
                    language = "english", 
                    removeNumbers = TRUE,
                    removePunctuation = TRUE,
                    stemWords = FALSE, 
                    weighting = weightTf)

mat <- as.matrix(matrix)
list <- rowSums(matrix)
rowTotals <- apply(matrix , 1, sum)
matrix.new   <- matrix[rowTotals > 0]

lda <- LDA(matrix, 250)
```

I want to convert the code above, to python code for RPy2. I have tried this yet:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
RTT = importr('RTextTools')
tmod = importr('topicmodels')
tm = importr('tm')

#CommentBunch is a list of strings.

matrix = RTT.create_matrix(CommentBunch, 
                           language = "english", 
                           removeNumber = True, 
                           removePunctuation = True, 
                           stemWords = True, 
                           weighting = tm.weightTf)

lda = tmod.LDA(matrix, 250)
```

Following is the DEBUG log:

```
 Connection to database established!
 Error in (function (x, k, method = "VEM", control = NULL, model = NULL,  :
 Each row of the input matrix needs to contain at least one non-zero entry

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Requirements\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpdb2.py", line 14499, in <module>
 ret = rpdb2.main()
 File "C:\Requirements\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpdb2.py", line 14470, in main
 StartServer(_rpdb2_args, fchdir, _rpdb2_pwd, fAllowUnencrypted, fAllowRemote, secret)
 File "C:\Requirements\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpdb2.py", line 14220, in StartServer
 imp.load_source('__main__', _path)
 File "c:\requirements\msr\msr14-mysql\rpylda.py", line 69, in <module>
 lda = tmod.LDA(matrix, 20)
 File "C:\Requirements\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 86, in __call__
 return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Requirements\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 35, in __call__
 res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
 rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in (function (x, k, method = "VEM", control
 = NULL, model = NULL,  :
 Each row of the input matrix needs to contain at least one non-zero entry
```

How am I supposed to convert the R code to RPy2 code for Python?
Please help!

Comment: what is the result of your current attempt?

Comment: @JoanSmith I have added a Debug log.

Comment: I don't know if its just a typo, but in the R example you have stemWords = FALSE and in the python version, stemWords = True. Also, in the R version, you filter you rows with sum 0 to create matrix.new, but then don't use this in your call to LDA. Is this deliberate?